# Unexpected outcome from model inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django

I've built a custom user model called "Administrator" for superuser purpose, and the other model called "Customer" for normal user purpose.

I intended to separate them into two different tables, it partly worked but not perfectly. The problem is that when I created an instance for Customer, the instance will be automatically added into the Administrators table, this isn't what I want.

[Administrator model on Django admin site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmS0E.png)

[Customer model on Django admin site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4J9X.png)

**Administrator model shown below:**

```
class Administrator(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    join_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    objects = AdministratorManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

**Customer model shown below:**

```
class Customer(Administrator):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=False)
    DOB = models.DateField()
    security_question1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=False)
    security_question2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=False)
    security_question_answer1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=False)
    security_question_answer2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=False)

    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'DOB', 'security_question1', 'security_question2']

    is_active = True
    is_admin = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrongly inherited the **`Customer`** model. It should be inherited from **`AbstractBaseUser`** as

```
class Customer(AbstractBaseUser):
    #Your code
```

**UPDATE-1**
You can use **`Abstract`** class for inheriting.
Define a `base class` as Abstract and inherit from that class might help you

```
class BaseClass(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    join_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    objects = AdministratorManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Administrator(BaseClass):
    pass


class Customer(BaseClass):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=False)
    DOB = models.DateField()
    security_question1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=False)
    security_question2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=False)
    security_question_answer1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=False)
    security_question_answer2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='', blank=False)

    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'DOB', 'security_question1', 'security_question2']

    is_active = True
    is_admin = False
```

Comment: Sorry for my confusing wording. I want the Customer model extends and inherits  from the Administrator model, and Customer instances will not be automatically added into Administrator table. Is possible to do this?